# In theory, can an extra election be cancelled once called?

Tags: election, united-kingdom

On 19 April 2017, the UK Parliament approved a motion for an early general election, to be held on 8 June ([BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-39643804)).

In theory, could Parliament later pass a motion to cancel the extra election?

Comment: Basically no if Parliament's dissolved since motions can't be passed

Comment: @Panda Good one!

Comment: isn't that why they got them one of those monarchs? :) </snooty_colonial>